# How to process frames using OpenCV with socketsrc Gstreamer pipeline in RTSP server?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have this pipeline using an RTSP server with gstreamer. I really want to get the frame after the `socketsrc`, process it with opencv and then push it back to the pipeline.

I tried to use `appsrc` with `appsink` using the official tutorial

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html?gi-language=c

```
 pipeline = "("
                     "socketsrc name= socket_src !  application/x-rtp , payload = 96  ,clock-rate=90000 ! "
                     "rtpjitterbuffer name= jitter_buffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse name= parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "
                     ")";



GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(p_server);
GstRTSPMediaFactory *new_factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_profiles(new_factory, GST_RTSP_PROFILE_AVP);

gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(new_factory, pipeline.c_str());
g_signal_connect(new_factory, "media-configure", (GCallback)media_configure_cb, this);

std::cout << domain_name << std::endl;

gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(new_factory, false);

gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, domain_name.c_str(), new_factory);
g_object_unref(mounts);
```

I would like to get ideas, how I can get the frame process it and push it back to the pipeline.

thanks!

Comment: I think an easier option would be to write a plugin that does the opencv tasks. You can refer to a number of examples in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/tree/discontinued-for-monorepo/ext/opencv here. I create plugins that receive raw frames from a plugin in gstreamer and perform some tasks with opencv and pass the buffer to the next element.

Comment: @GuruGovindan do you have a guide on how to do it? it looks a little bit complicated..

Comment: gsttextoverlay.cpp is a good example. It is a quite simple plugin and self contained. You can use that as the base and then modify the opencv methods to call the ones you need. That plugin in particular only uses `cv::putText` to overlay a text. The buffer you get in `*_overlay_transform()` will be of the form `cv::Mat img` which will be compatible with opencv. Once you are done doing things with opencv forward the buffer with `GST_FLOW_OK`.

Comment: @GuruGovindan To add plugins do I have to build GStreamer from source, and add plugins? Is it possible to use the terminal pipeline with building from source? 

Thanks!